# How do I get all the prices history with binance API for a crypto using Python?

Tags: python, api, cryptocurrency, binance

I've been using this script to get the prices from some cryptocurrencies using Binance API and this script:
https://steemit.com/python/@marketstack/how-to-download-historical-price-data-from-binance-with-python

The problem is that with this script I cannot control the date range: for example, I want to choose the period range between Dec. 2015 and Dec. 2020, or I want the DAILY PRICES from the first day trading for any crypto ...etc.

So I share with you the code I'm using (copied from the steemit code and modified a little bit)
How can I do it?

```
# https://steemit.com/python/@marketstack/how-to-download-historical-price-data-from-binance-with-python###

import requests 
import json 
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np  
import datetime as dt  

frequency = input("Please enter the frequency (1m/5m/30m/.../1h/6h/1d/ :  ")

def get_bars(symbol, interval=frequency):
    root_url = 'https://api.binance.com/api/v1/klines'
    url = root_url + '?symbol=' + symbol + '&interval=' + interval
    data = json.loads(requests.get(url).text)
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df.columns = ['open_time',
                  'o', 'h', 'l', 'c', 'v',
                  'close_time', 'qav', 'num_trades',
                  'taker_base_vol', 'taker_quote_vol', 'ignore']
    df.index = [dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(x / 1000.0) for x in df.close_time]
    return df

btcusdt = get_bars('BTCUSDT')
ethusdt = get_bars('ETHUSDT')


df0=pd.DataFrame(btcusdt)
df0.to_csv('_btcusdt.csv')

df1=pd.DataFrame(ethusdt)
df1.to_csv('_ethusdt.csv')
```

Can anyone help me to optimize it?

Answer (score 12):

I am using this out of the binance documentation : https://python-binance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/binance.html?highlight=get_historical_klines#binance.client.Client.get_historical_klines

```
import os
from binance.client import Client
import pandas as pd
import datetime, time

def GetHistoricalData(self, howLong):
    self.howLong = howLong
    # Calculate the timestamps for the binance api function
    self.untilThisDate = datetime.datetime.now()
    self.sinceThisDate = self.untilThisDate - datetime.timedelta(days = self.howLong)
    # Execute the query from binance - timestamps must be converted to strings !
    self.candle = self.client.get_historical_klines("BNBBTC", Client.KLINE_INTERVAL_1MINUTE, str(self.sinceThisDate), str(self.untilThisDate))

    # Create a dataframe to label all the columns returned by binance so we work with them later.
    self.df = pd.DataFrame(self.candle, columns=['dateTime', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume', 'closeTime', 'quoteAssetVolume', 'numberOfTrades', 'takerBuyBaseVol', 'takerBuyQuoteVol', 'ignore'])
    # as timestamp is returned in ms, let us convert this back to proper timestamps.
    self.df.dateTime = pd.to_datetime(self.df.dateTime, unit='ms').dt.strftime(Constants.DateTimeFormat)
    self.df.set_index('dateTime', inplace=True)

    # Get rid of columns we do not need
    self.df = self.df.drop(['closeTime', 'quoteAssetVolume', 'numberOfTrades', 'takerBuyBaseVol','takerBuyQuoteVol', 'ignore'], axis=1)

    print(self.df)
```

I do hope this helps someone.

(Please note this method is cut out of a class I have, so you may get rid of all of the self-s) , and you need to have your client set up before by

`client = Client(api_key, api_secret)`

Any improvements are of course welcome !

Comment: what is Constants ?

Comment: Hi @SaeidMohammadiNejati, Constants is just a py file i have to store all of static strings etc. The DateTimeFormat within there looks like this: 

DateTimeFormat = "%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S"

Overall in the program i refer to this, therefore if i need to change for some reason I only change it in constants.py

Answer (score 6):

This is a function that I used.
Start and end are dates in Unix timestamp format. Interval is graph interval.

And keep in mind Binance did not exist in Dec 2015 :-)

```py
def get_klines_iter(symbol, interval, start, end, limit=5000):
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    startDate = end
    while startDate>start:
        url = 'https://api.binance.com/api/v3/klines?symbol=' + \
            symbol + '&interval=' + interval + '&limit='  + str(iteration)
        if startDate is not None:
            url += '&endTime=' + str(startDate)
        
        df2 = pd.read_json(url)
        df2.columns = ['Opentime', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume', 'Closetime', 'Quote asset volume', 'Number of trades','Taker by base', 'Taker buy quote', 'Ignore']
        df = pd.concat([df2, df], axis=0, ignore_index=True, keys=None)
        startDate = df.Opentime[0]   
    df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)    
    return df
```

Comment: It doesn't work T_T 
problem with get_klines_iter(symbol....)

Comment: Change it to: `def get_klines_iter(symbol, interval, start, end, limit=5000):`

Comment: I'm getting this error: ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 0 elements, new values have 12 elements

Answer (score 3):

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
import requests
from typing import *
import time

class BinanceClient:
    def __init__(self, futures=False):
        self.exchange = "BINANCE"
        self.futures = futures

        if self.futures:
            self._base_url = "https://fapi.binance.com"
        else:
            self._base_url = "https://api.binance.com"

        self.symbols = self._get_symbols()

    def _make_request(self, endpoint: str, query_parameters: Dict):
        try:
            response = requests.get(self._base_url + endpoint, params=query_parameters)
        except Exception as e:
            print("Connection error while making request to %s: %s", endpoint, e)
            return None

        if response.status_code == 200:
            return response.json()
        else:
            print("Error while making request to %s: %s (status code = %s)",
                         endpoint, response.json(), response.status_code)
            return None

    def _get_symbols(self) -> List[str]:

        params = dict()

        endpoint = "/fapi/v1/exchangeInfo" if self.futures else "/api/v3/exchangeInfo"
        data = self._make_request(endpoint, params)

        symbols = [x["symbol"] for x in data["symbols"]]

        return symbols

    def get_historical_data(self, symbol: str, interval: Optional[str] = "1m", start_time: Optional[int] = None, end_time: Optional[int] = None, limit: Optional[int] = 1500):

        params = dict()

        params["symbol"] = symbol
        params["interval"] = interval
        params["limit"] = limit

        if start_time is not None:
            params["startTime"] = start_time
        if end_time is not None:
            params["endTime"] = end_time

        endpoint = "/fapi/v1/klines" if self.futures else "/api/v3/klines"
        raw_candles = self._make_request(endpoint, params)

        candles = []

        if raw_candles is not None:
            for c in raw_candles:
                candles.append((float(c[0]), float(c[1]), float(c[2]), float(c[3]), float(c[4]), float(c[5]),))
            return candles
        else:
            return None

def ms_to_dt_utc(ms: int) -> datetime:
    return datetime.utcfromtimestamp(ms / 1000)

def ms_to_dt_local(ms: int) -> datetime:
    return datetime.fromtimestamp(ms / 1000)

def GetDataFrame(data):
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Timestamp', "Open", "High", "Low", "Close", "Volume"])
    df["Timestamp"] = df["Timestamp"].apply(lambda x: ms_to_dt_local(x))
    df['Date'] = df["Timestamp"].dt.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
    df['Time'] = df["Timestamp"].dt.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    column_names = ["Date", "Time", "Open", "High", "Low", "Close", "Volume"]
    df = df.set_index('Timestamp')
    df = df.reindex(columns=column_names)

    return df

def GetHistoricalData(client, symbol, start_time, end_time, limit=1500):
    collection = []

    while start_time < end_time:
        data = client.get_historical_data(symbol, start_time=start_time, end_time=end_time, limit=limit)
        print(client.exchange + " " + symbol + " : Collected " + str(len(data)) + " initial data from "+ str(ms_to_dt_local(data[0][0])) +" to " + str(ms_to_dt_local(data[-1][0])))
        start_time = int(data[-1][0] + 1000)
        collection +=data
        time.sleep(1.1)

    return collection
    
client = BinanceClient(futures=False)
symbol = "BTCUSDT"
interval = "1m"
fromDate = int(datetime.strptime('2021-11-15', '%Y-%m-%d').timestamp() * 1000)
toDate = int(datetime.strptime('2021-11-16', '%Y-%m-%d').timestamp() * 1000)

data = GetHistoricalData(client, symbol, fromDate, toDate)
df = GetDataFrame(data)
df
```

Comment: the data seems mismatch with real data.

Comment: @ChauGiang check that both the timezones are of the same format

Comment: Yes, they are the same format (UTC)

Comment: I even print `klines` (line 6) and found the data is not correct

Comment: @ChauGiang https://github.com/souparno/Backtesting-Crypto-Trading-Strategies/blob/master/Binance-backtesting.ipynb

Comment: @ChauGiang check updated post

Comment: I have checked the response data (in my case it is spot data) but it does not look as same as the data from Binance/Trading view chart

Answer (score 1):

based on Mike Malyi and isnvi23h4's answer:

Please use python >= 3.7, the code does not need to install any dependencies

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timezone, timedelta
import calendar

def get_klines_iter(symbol, interval, start, end = None, limit=1000):
    # start and end must be isoformat YYYY-MM-DD
    # We are using utc time zone

    # the maximum records is 1000 per each Binance API call

    df = pd.DataFrame()

    if start is None:
        print('start time must not be None')
        return
    start = calendar.timegm(datetime.fromisoformat(start).timetuple()) * 1000

    if end is None:
        dt = datetime.now(timezone.utc)
        utc_time = dt.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc)
        end = int(utc_time.timestamp()) * 1000
        return
    else:
        end = calendar.timegm(datetime.fromisoformat(end).timetuple()) * 1000
    last_time = None

    while len(df) == 0 or (last_time is not None and last_time < end):
        url = 'https://api.binance.com/api/v3/klines?symbol=' + \
              symbol + '&interval=' + interval + '&limit=1000'
        if(len(df) == 0):
            url += '&startTime=' + str(start)
        else:
            url += '&startTime=' + str(last_time)

        url += '&endTime=' + str(end)
        df2 = pd.read_json(url)
        df2.columns = ['Opentime', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume', 'Closetime',
                       'Quote asset volume', 'Number of trades', 'Taker by base', 'Taker buy quote', 'Ignore']
        dftmp = pd.DataFrame()
        dftmp = pd.concat([df2, dftmp], axis=0, ignore_index=True, keys=None)

        dftmp.Opentime = pd.to_datetime(dftmp.Opentime, unit='ms')
        dftmp['Date'] = dftmp.Opentime.dt.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
        dftmp['Time'] = dftmp.Opentime.dt.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        dftmp = dftmp.drop(['Quote asset volume', 'Closetime', 'Opentime',
                      'Number of trades', 'Taker by base', 'Taker buy quote', 'Ignore'], axis=1)
        column_names = ["Date", "Time", "Open", "High", "Low", "Close", "Volume"]
        dftmp.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
        dftmp = dftmp.reindex(columns=column_names)
        string_dt = str(dftmp['Date'][len(dftmp) - 1]) + 'T' + str(dftmp['Time'][len(dftmp) - 1]) + '.000Z'
        utc_last_time = datetime.strptime(string_dt, "%d/%m/%YT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
        last_time = (utc_last_time - datetime(1970, 1, 1)) // timedelta(milliseconds=1)
        df = pd.concat([df, dftmp], axis=0, ignore_index=True, keys=None)
    df.to_csv('0y_eth_only17andnew.csv', sep='\t', index=False)
get_klines_iter('ETHBUSD', '30m', '2022-01-01', '2022-02-21')
```

Answer (score 1):

I do it like this:

```
def get_binance_data(api_key, pair, countdown='open', interval='4h', start='1 Jan 2018', end=None):
  client = Client(api_key=api_key)
  intervals = {
      '15m': Client.KLINE_INTERVAL_15MINUTE,
      '1h':  Client.KLINE_INTERVAL_1HOUR,      
      '4h':  Client.KLINE_INTERVAL_4HOUR,
      '1d':  Client.KLINE_INTERVAL_1DAY
  }
  interval = intervals.get(interval, '4h')
  print(f'Historical interval {interval}')
  klines = client.get_historical_klines(symbol=pair, interval=interval, start_str=start, end_str=end)
  data = pd.DataFrame(klines)
  data.columns = ['open_time','open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume','close_time', 'qav','num_trades','taker_base_vol','taker_quote_vol', 'ignore']
  data.index = [pd.to_datetime(x, unit='ms').strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') for x in data.open_time]
  usecols=['open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume']
  data = data[usecols]
  data = data.astype('float')
  return data



api_key = 'хххх...xxx' # use your api-key
symbol = 'ETHUSDT'
eth = get_binance_data(api_key, symbol)
eth.head()
```

Output:

```
Historical interval 4h
                    open    high    low     close   volume
2018-01-01 00:00:00 733.01  737.99  716.80  734.50  8739.23361
2018-01-01 04:00:00 734.99  763.55  730.01  751.99  9492.34734
2018-01-01 08:00:00 751.77  759.00  730.58  741.01  8939.36851
2018-01-01 12:00:00 741.01  752.27  724.15  748.80  11284.08664
2018-01-01 16:00:00 748.27  749.98  733.00  746.23  7757.00362
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests

market = 'ETHEUR'
tick_interval = '1d'

url = 'https://api.binance.com/api/v3/klines?symbol='+market+'&interval='+tick_interval
data = requests.get(url).json()

print(data)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).