# How to get historical data for multiple coins in python-binance?

Tags: python, data-science, binance-api-client

I want to get historical data for more than 100 cryptocurrencies with Binance API but when I execute the code I only get the data for one coin. Example code is:

```
binance_symbols = ['BTCUSDT', 'ETHUSDT', 'XRPUSDT', 'SOLUSDT']

for symbol in binance_symbols:
    klines = pd.DataFrame(client.get_historical_klines(symbol, "1h", "1 Aug, 2021", "24 Sep, 2021"))
```

Is there any alternative way to get data of all coins?

Comment: I think this might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66295187/how-do-i-get-all-the-prices-history-with-binance-api-for-a-crypto-using-python

Answer (score 0):

With each cycle of the for-loop, you are overwriting the old Dataframe, because you are declaring `klines` over and over again. A better way is to make an empty Dataframe and then append the data for the other coins.

**Example:**

```py
binance_symbols = ['BTCUSDT', 'ETHUSDT', 'XRPUSDT', 'SOLUSDT']
klines = client.get_historical_klines(binance_symbols[0], "1h", "1 Aug, 2021", "24 Sep, 2021")

for symbol in binance_symbols[1:]:
    new_df = pd.DataFrame(client.get_historical_klines(symbol, "1h", "1 Aug, 2021", "24 Sep, 2021"))
    klines.append(new_df)
```

Comment: It did not work. I get same result, I only get SOLUSDT datas.

Comment: @nostalgia Could you specify the output of the function ```client.get_historical_klines(...)```? I need it to fix my answer.

Comment: Thank you @MarcelloZago, this is the output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3o4K.png

Also I tried below but it did not work:

`binance_symbols = ['BTCUSDT', 'ETHUSDT', 'XRPUSDT', 'SOLUSDT']
new_df = []
klines = client.get_historical_klines(binance_symbols[0], "1h", "1 Aug, 2021", "24 Sep, 2021")

for symbol in binance_symbols[1:]:
    new_df = pd.DataFrame(client.get_historical_klines(symbol, "1h", "1 Aug, 2021", "24 Sep, 2021"))
    klines.append(new_df)`

Answer (score 0):

```
binance_symbols = ['BTCUSDT', 'ETHUSDT', 'SOLUSDT']
klines = []

for symbol in binance_symbols:
    new_df = pd.DataFrame(client.get_historical_klines(symbol, Client.KLINE_INTERVAL_1DAY, '1 Jan 2020'))
    klines.append(new_df)
```

Comment: Please, add a brief explanation of how/why it solves the problem.